How do i refresh the data of the user that was initially logged in to spotify for my spotipy app?
I have a Flask application developed using Spotipy and OAuth, where i will fetch the current liked songs of a spotify account, the problem is that for some reason the data for only one user is being used, regardless of who i log into spotiify. How can i refresh the saved account data?
I'll share the entire code:
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from flask import Flask, url_for, session, request, redirect
import json
import time
import pandas as pd

# App config
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'SOMETHING-RANDOM'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'spotify-login-session'

@app.route('/')
def login():
    session.clear()
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
    session["token_info"] = token_info
    return redirect("/getTracks")

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    for key in list(session.keys()):
        session.pop(key)
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/getTracks')
def get_all_tracks():
    session['token_info'], authorized = get_token()
    session.modified = True
    if not authorized:
        return redirect('/')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=session.get('token_info').get('access_token'))
    user = sp.current_user()
    results = []
    iter = 0
    while True:
        offset = iter * 50
        iter += 1
        curGroup = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=50, offset=offset)['items']
        for idx, item in enumerate(curGroup):
            track = item['track']
            val = track['name'] + " - " + track['artists'][0]['name']
            results += [val]
        if (len(curGroup) < 50):
            break
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["song names"]) 
    df.to_csv('songs.csv', index=False)
    return user


# Checks to see if token is valid and gets a new token if not
def get_token():
    token_valid = False
    token_info = session.get("token_info", {})

    # Checking if the session already has a token stored
    if not (session.get('token_info', False)):
        token_valid = False
        return token_info, token_valid

    # Checking if token has expired
    now = int(time.time())
    is_token_expired = session.get('token_info').get('expires_at') - now < 60

    # Refreshing token if it has expired
    if (is_token_expired):
        sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
        token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(session.get('token_info').get('refresh_token'))

    token_valid = True
    return token_info, token_valid


def create_spotify_oauth():
    return SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id="id",
            client_secret="secret",
            redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorize',
            scope="user-library-read")

